# How to pass the varchar parameter when the onclick function of javascript is pressed?

Tags: javascript, php

May I know how to pass a varchar parameter to an onClick function, the varchar parameter is the uuid that stored in my database table and i use mysqli_fetch_array to retrieve them. A list of items will display in my html and each item is assigned with the button, when the button is pressed , it will display the uuid of the particular item in the alert window. I am able to that when the id is numeric or integer, but when I change it into the uuid or md5 id or the string, the value is failed to pass, and the button is stuck. Here is some part of my code.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"
onClick="deletefun(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>)"
title="Delete">delete</button>`

When the deletefun button is pressed, the alert window will pop out to display  the uuid of the particular item in the list.

`<script>function deletefun(data){
   alert(data);
 </script>`

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Your html/javascript code is inside a .php file? If not, your php code is not interpreted.

Comment: Ya, in the php file. @roberto06 has solvd my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add quotes around `<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>` in your button :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"
onClick="deletefun('<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>')"
title="Delete">delete</button>
```

Without these quotes, the function treats `<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>` as if it was the name of a variable instead of a string.

Comment: Thank you roberto06, after add in the quote, the code work.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as accepted if you're satisfied ;)